# Introspecting stored values of a field

Tags: solr

I have field string field 'tags' and I want to list all indexed values for 'tag' from Solr.
Is there some introspection API in order to get hold of all values as JSON or XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TermsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent).
The TermsComponent SearchComponent is a simple component that provides access to the indexed terms in a field and the number of documents that match each term.

This will return all the indexed terms. You can specify the field for which you want to retrieve the terms for.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/terms?terms.fl=tag&terms.sort=index
```